# What sort of URL structure should be used to display AMP HTML vs vanilla HTML

Tags: seo, amp-html

There's an existing wordpress plugin that creates AMP formats automatically by adding `/amp` onto the end of any posts URL. I'm worried about duplicating my content at multiple URLs and wondering if adding some parameter like `?v=amp` would be better? Also, if a parameter is used to render the page via AMP, how do we let Google know about these pages? Can we submit a separate AMP sitemap?

Comment: I have asked to have this question deleted. Waiting on a moderator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMP standard uses a Canonical link to define the original source and a link rel=amphtml on the canonical page to point to the amp version.  Google understands both so no action is needed on your part if you amp pages pass validation.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Don't know why I didn't see that before.